# Confused about the Photoelectric Effect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

If an incident photon with frequency ***f*** hits a metal with a work force of ***w***:
How do I find the color of the incident photon and the threshold frequency of the metal?

What equations are necessary to find the color and threshold frequency?

Is there an easy explanation for this?

Comment: A quick google search, and wikipedia read would probably be quite fruitful.

Comment: @zhermes - I've been searching for an hour and I have no idea how to find the frequency of metal, only the frequency of a photon.

Comment: The very first article in a google search is [wikipedia's photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect).  The article defines a metal's threshold frequency [within roughly the first page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Experimental_observations_of_photoelectric_emission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should re-read the question, because "frequency of the metal" doesn't make much sense in this context. And the color of photon is dependant only on it's frequency which is given. Do you need some further explanations on that?

Photoeffect's main equation is one of energy balance. The only energy source in this event is the photon whose energy is $hf$. If that is enough to eject an electron ($\ge w$), the emission occurs. The leftover energy becomes kinetic energy of the electron.
$$hf=w+K$$

The threshold is the case where you get just enough energy to emit the electron but no leftover. The needed equation is $$hf=w$$

Comment: I meant "threshold frequency of the metal" sorry. :(

Comment: Also, to find the color, I needed to find the wavelength in nm.

Comment: The equation for that is c/f = lambda

Comment: So you're saying that to find the threshold frequency of the metal, you have to divide w/h?

Comment: Yes, w/h is correct.